# Do transformers return current to source when magnetic field collapse at primary coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

When we close the circut containing an inductor and a battery, the current starts flowing, which builds magnetic field around inductor, changing magnetic field produces its own current in opposite direction which stops the main current from flowing temporarily and after some time the magnetic field is fully built up and no more changes, which stops inducing current in opposite direction and main current starts flowing again, at this stage the magnetic field around the inductor is full, and when the main current is stopped or reversed, the fully built magnetic field collapses which induces very high voltage in the circut in opposite direction; similarly when the primary current is stopped or reversed in a transformer, does its magnetic flux in the core changes direction or collapses and induces very high voltage in the opposite direction in the primary coil?
My question pertains to the situation when the secondary is on load and without load.

Comment: Very hard to follow your 17 line single sentence

Comment: Bob D the width of your screen appears to be small, try reading it on bigger screen, the lines may reduce.